# Specified Cast is not Valid - trying to cast a char

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to cast a char as follows:

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
  VM VMResult = new VM();
  VMResult.status = (char)Reader["status"];
  VMList.Add(VMResult);
}
```

Then comes the fun part: `Specified Cast is not Valid.`

VMResult.status is a char

The returned data is a char(1) in sql

I assume there must be a difference in the C# / SQL char terminology.

What do you think?

Comment: `char(10)` is a `string`. Debug your code and inspect the type of `Reader["status"]`.

Comment: try to cast it to a string and see if it works. Also +1 for inspecting `reader["status"]` type in debugger

Comment: it works if i change the VMResult.status to be type string.  I've already done that, just wanted to see if this is possible to get working and why if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume there must be a difference in the C# / SQL char terminology.

That's correct. A char in sql server is a fixed length character string. It can be nullable.

A char in .net is a structure that represents a single character as a UTF-16 code unit. It cannot be null since its a structure

There is no fixed length character string .Net unless you consider a char array or byte array a fixed length string.

Since most of the .net ecosystem has better support for strings than chars, char arrays or byte arrays, you're much better off just using the string that gets returned for the char(x) fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that `Reader["status"]` will always be a char (or you only want the first char), and the current type of `Reader["status"]` is a `string` you can always

```
VMResult.status = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Reader["status"])) ? 
                      Reader["status"].ToCharArray()[0] : '';
```

**EDIT:** null checking ftw.

Answer (score 0):

OK so you basically want to cast a string to a char, this is going to assume that your "status" value is a single character string:

```
VMResult.status = Reader["status"].ToString()[0];
```

this also assumes Reader[] does not already return a string (if it did then the `ToString` is not required) and that the value is not null.